# bluebird npm TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null

Tags: node.js, express, npm, bluebird

I am using bluebird npm,I am getting the above error

I am calling three different function & doing some database operation, but I am getting this error.

If I tried with two functions, it is working but with three function it is throwing error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null.

If you go to bluebird/js/release/using.js and comment the line no 39 ;

If I comment this line, then this issue is not coming & all is working fine.

If you want more info please [Click Here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1356)

```
This is main.js

var myModule = require('../lib/myModule');
var sync = require('deasync');

var id = 90;
var moduleObj = new moduleEntity(id);
console.log(moduleObj);

var id = 90;
var moduleObj = new moduleEntity(id);
console.log(moduleObj);

var id = 90;
var moduleObj = new moduleEntity(id);
console.log(moduleObj);

In MyModule.js

var deasync = require('deasync');
var dbEntity = require('../db/dbEntity');

module.exports = function (id) {
var outputEntity;
dbEntity(id, function(data){
outputEntity = data
});
while(outputEntity === undefined) { deasync.runLoopOnce();};
return outputEntity;

};

In dbEntery.js

var Promise = require("bluebird");
var getConnection = require('./dbcon');

module.exports = function (id,cb) {
var sql_getRecords = SELECT * from tanle_name;

Promise.using(getConnection, function (conn) {
    return conn.query(sql_getRecords).then(function(data){
        cb(data[0]);
    })
});
};
```

**Here is error stack trace**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null
at FunctionDisposer.doDispose (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/using.js:98:18)
at FunctionDisposer.Disposer.tryDispose (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/using.js:78:20)
at iterator (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/using.js:36:53)
at dispose (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/using.js:48:9)
at /home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/using.js:194:20
at PassThroughHandlerContext.finallyHandler (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/finally.js:55:23)
at PassThroughHandlerContext.tryCatcher (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:687:18)
at Async._drainQueue (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/user/Projects/project_name/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:651:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:624:5)
```

Bluebird version -- 3.5

Node Version -- v7.6.0

Comment: Post the relevant code here directly as text.

Comment: @ Carcigenicate, thanks for replay, please click on Github Issue Link, as I have given in my question

Comment: No, post the relevant code here. Don't link to code. Links rots, and it's unacceptable to expect people to dig through code to find the relevant bits.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I have attached the code. As I said in my question, If I comment bluebird/js/release/using.js on line no 39, then it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You provided no code examples so it's hard to give you any detailed answer but here are some things that you have to keep in mind when you get error like this.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null` means that some code (also impossible to tell you which code because you didn't provide an example and full error stack trace) tries to bind some function to some `this` object and arguments using `Function.prototype.call()` - see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

but instead of the function it got `null`.

Now you need to follow the stack trace and see which code is trying to call the function and where the null originated to fix your problem.

Note that it is `null` and not `undefined` so it must have been provided explicitly instead of just being a missing argument to a function call or a missing property on an object. This is an important hint that should let you diagnose the problem much easier.